# Rails 4: Being able to select multiple instances of one model when creating the model it has a has_many :through relationship with

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, has-many-through

When I add a new `Book` to my `Library`, I want to be able to specify what `Shelves` (**note:** "`Shelf`" is the term I used in my app for the model that groups `Books` together within a `Library`; a better name for this model would have been `Category` or `Genre`, but I was stupid) in that `Library` it should belong to. Right now, I'm able to add a `Book` to my `Library`, but I'm having issues with the `Shelves`. I'm pretty new at learning Rails and I'd appreciate any help.

**Models**

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :library, dependent: :destroy
  ...
end
```

library.rb:

```
class Library < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :shelves, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :catalogs, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :books, :through => :catalogs, dependent: :destroy
  ...
end
```

book.rb:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :catalogs, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :libraries, :through => :catalogs, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :bookshelves, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :shelves, :through => :bookshelves, dependent: :destroy
  ...
end
```

catalog.rb:

```
class Catalog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :library
end
```

shelf.rb:

```
class Shelf < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :library
  has_many :bookshelves, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :books, :through => :bookshelves, dependent: :destroy
  ...
end
```

bookshelf.rb

```
class Bookshelf < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :shelf
end
```

**Controller**

books_controller.rb

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def create
    @book = Book.new(book_params)
    @library = current_user.library

    if @book.save
      @book.catalogs.create(:library_id => @library.id)
      flash[:success] = "Book added to library!"
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      render 'current_user'
    end
  end

  ...

  private
    def book_params
      params.require(:book).permit(:title, :author, :publisher, :isbn)
    end

    ...
end
```

**View**

_book_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@book) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: "Book Title" %>
    <%= f.text_field :author, placeholder: "Author" %>
    <%= f.text_field :publisher, placeholder: "Publisher" %>
    <%= f.text_field :isbn, placeholder: "ISBN" %>

    <%= f.fields_for :catalogs do |ff| %>
      <%= ff.hidden_field :library_id %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.fields_for :bookshelves do |ff| %>
      <%= ff.collection_select :shelf_ids, current_user.library.shelves.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, {}, multiple: true %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Add Book to Library", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: In your code, a `book` can be on many `shelves`. That doesn't make much sense to me. It would be better for a `book` to `belong_to` a `shelf` and a `shelf` have many `books`. That would eliminate the `bookshelf` model, which seems redundant at this point.

Comment: "Shelf" is the term I used within my app for grouping Books within a Library together. Think of a Shelf as a category and Books can belong to several different categories within a Library. Yeah, my wording of the models is confusing. I was trying to be cute by coming up with my own terminology. Live and learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `book_params` method, you don't have `shelf_ids` listed. So it won't be passed into the `.new` method and thus it won't be saved. Since you wan't multiple `ids`, you want to do this:

```
def book_params
  params.require(:book).permit(:title, :author, :publisher, :isbn, shelf_ids: [])
end
```

That way, the controller knows it's an array and not just a single value.

Oh, and btw, `shelf_ids` and any other array values like that **must** be at the end or it will throw an error.

Edit:

Also change this part of code:

```
<%= f.fields_for :bookshelves do |ff| %>
  <%= ff.collection_select :shelf_ids, current_user.library.shelves.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, {}, multiple: true %>
<% end %>
```

to this:

```
<%= f.collection_select :shelf_ids, current_user.library.shelves.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, {}, multiple: true %>
```

You don't need to worry about the `through` part of the association. Just set up the `has_many` part and it'll work.

Comment: I've added that and it's still not adding the newly created Book to the selected Shelves. Do you think I'd have to do anything with `bookshelves` in the controller?

Comment: Ah, didn't see you wrapped it in a `fields_for` tag. Try removing the tag and changing `ff.collection_select` to `f.collection_select`

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! You have no idea how long that was giving me trouble. :)

Comment: Glad I could help. With `has_many :through` relationships, setting up the `has_many` part is all that's needed. The `through` part takes care of itself.